# problems with transformations XML to Python

Tags: python, xml

Does anyone knows why I have this error on output of my Python document? I'm using lxml element etree.
The error shows up when I define the functions
...............................................................................................................................................................

```
List all purchases of the year chosen by the user:
Buy: 2017/12/01, Delivered, Ship all over as each product is available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D: \ ABC \ 1stan \ 1st Semester \ TI \ tp3 \ python \ ola.py", line 
55, in <module>
    printCompras (treeDoc, "2017", prefix)
  File "D: \ ABC \ 1styear \ 1st Semester \ TI \ tp3 \ python \ ola.py", 
line 20, in printCompras
    printCompra (compraElem, prefix)
  File "D: \ ABC \ 1styear \ 1st Semester \ TI \ tp3 \ python \ ola.py", 
line 34, in printCompra
    "+", "+ buy_id [0] .text +", "+ buy_id [0] .text +", "+ buy_id [0] .text 
+ )
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My Python file:

```
from lxml import etree

file = "loja.xml"
treeDoc = etree.parse (file)

buyElem = treeDoc.xpath ("// purchase")
listUsers = treeDoc.xpath ("// user")
productElem = treeDoc.xpath ("// product")
characteristicaElem = treeDoc.xpath ("// product / technical_characters /   
feature")
olamundo = treeDoc.xpath ("// purchase / product_bought")
print ("List all Purchases of the year chosen by the user:")
prefix = ""

def printCompras (treeDoc, year, prefix):
    for purchase in compraElem:
        buy_date = purchase.xpath ("purchase_date")
        ano_data = (buy_date [0] .text) .split ("/")
        buy_year = year_data [0]
        if year == year_of_buy:
            printCompra (compraElem, prefix)


def printCompra (compraElem, prefix):
    for purchase in compraElem:
        buyer_id = buyElem [0] .get ("buyer")
        for user in listaUsers:
            user_name = user.xpath ("@ user_id =" + buyer_id + "/ name")
        compra_id = compra.xpath ("compra_id")
        buy_date = purchase.xpath ("purchase_date")
        buy_account = buy.xpath ("buy_account") [0]
        indication = purchase.xpath ("indication")
    for purchase in compraElem:
         print (prefix + "Buy:" + buy_date [0] .text + "," + buy_date.get 
("situation") + "," + indication [0] .text)
         "+", "+ buy_id [0] .text +", "+ buy_id [0] .text +", "+ buy_id [0] 
.text + )
         (+), "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "[ )
    for product in productElem:
        carrier = olamundo [0] .get ("carrier")
        printProduct (productName, carrier, prefix)

def printProduct (productEle, carrier, prefix):
product_id = olamundo [0] .get ("@ product_id")
product_name = treeDoc.xpath ("// buy [purchased_product / @ product_id =]")
price = treeDoc.xpath ("// product bla bla bla")
print (prefix + "Product:" + product_id + "," + name [0] .text + "," + price 
[0] .text + "," +
print (prefix + "Product:" + product_id + "," + olamundo [0] .get ("@ 
carrier"))

def printVender ():
    identifier, name, average-rating-in-stars

def printCaracteristica (characteristicElement, prefix):
name = characterElement.get ("name")
value = characterElement.get ("value")
print (prefix + "Characteristics:" + name + "-" + value)

printCompras (treeDoc, "2017", prefix)
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve], but short answer: if e.g. `buy_id [0]` (why the space?) causes an `IndexError` than `len(buy_id) == 0`. As to *why* it's empty, you'll need to do some debugging.

Comment: Your random inclusion of spaces/whitespace doesn't help to make this legible but I would assume you have an empty list in the response so that you can't take the 0th index.